Distance between two complex vectors up to a global phase
Is there a way to compute efficiently

where x and y are complex vectors ?
My goal is to reconstruct the signal y, but I can only do it up to a complex number of modulus 1, and so this quantity would be the reconstruction error.
I have looked a bit on the internet and found nothing, the best I can think about is to take random complex numbers of modulus 1 and take the minimum among these values.

See What is the best way to enter mathematics into the Stack Overflow question body?

That said, this seems to be more of a math question than a programming question, since if you had a working algo, you would just need to plug it in to Python. So you might want to ask on [math.se] Stack Exchange instead. Otherwise, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and if you want more tips, see [ask].

@wjandrea Thank you, I was wondering if there was already a library to solve this problem

hard to read

Are x and y just complex numbers, or are they whole vectors of values? This answer assumes that they are vectors of values with multiple complex components.
Does this work? Check it against your random trials. (Working at the bottom).
import numpy as np
import math

def minimiseNorm( x, y ):
    a, b = np.real( x ), np.imag( x )
    p, q = np.real( y ), np.imag( y )
    S1 = np.sum( a * p + b * q )       
    S2 = np.sum( a * q - b * p )     
    A = math.sqrt( S1 ** 2 + S2 ** 2 )
    phi = math.atan2( S2, S1 )        
    minNorm = math.sqrt( np.sum( a * a + b * b + p * p + q * q ) - 2 * A )
    c = math.cos( phi ) + 1j * math.sin( phi )
    return minNorm, c

x = np.array( [ 1+2j, 3+ 4j,  5+ 6j ] )
y = np.array( [ 7+8j, 9+10j, 11+12j ] )

N, c = minimiseNorm( x, y )
print( "Minimum norm is", N, " occurring at c=", c )

Somebody had better check my algebra.


Thank you, this seems to be right. It does better than my random method from what I've tried.

I've added the c value that minimises it now. Hope it's useful.

This actually looks like a relatively straightforward math (not Python) question.
I apologize.  Other forums let you use latex.  This one doesn't seem to.  I'll do my best since I don't know how to enter formulas.
In polar coordinates, let x = (r1, theta1) and y = (r2, theta2).
The possible values of cx are just points on the zero-centered unit circle of radius r1. You want the point on this circle closest to $y$, which clearly happens to be the point with the same angle as y, namely (r1, theta2).  So you want c to be (1, theta2-theta1) in polar coordinates.
In Python:
import cmath
_, theta1 = cmath.polar(x)
_, theta2 = cmath.polar(y)
c = cmath.rect(1, theta2 - theta1)

numpy has similar functions.
Actually, this can be simplified even further.  c is just the unit vector of y/x.  So this can all be done without polar coordinates.
t = y/x
c = t / abs(t)

or if you're playing Python golf:
c=(t:=y/x)/abs(t)

This works with both complex numbers and numpy arrays.

This works for complex numbers, but not for complex vectors where the arguments of each entry may be different.

@ed268.  Added additional info.
